# Removing the all space from the all text file

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple text files in particular location but files have empty space in last in first line. Please help in removing the all space from the all text file.

I have written the below VBA code but the same issue.

```
Sub RemoveSpacesFromTextFiles()
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim strFolderPath As String
    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim intFile As Integer
    
    ' Define the folder path containing the text files
    strFolderPath = "D:\Shamim Data\Desktop\UCB\Audit-UCB\Internal Audit FY 23-24\Brand Audit - 2023-24\Text File Project by  VBA\OutPut Text File\" ' Update with your folder path
    
    ' Create a FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Check if the folder exists
    If objFSO.FolderExists(strFolderPath) Then
        ' Get the folder object
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderPath)
        
        ' Loop through each file in the folder
        For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
            ' Check if the file is a text file
            If objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path) = "txt" Then
                ' Open the text file
                intFile = FreeFile
                Open objFile.Path For Input As intFile
                
                ' Read the contents of the file
                strTemp = ""
                Do While Not EOF(intFile)
                    Line Input #intFile, strFileName
                    strTemp = strTemp & Trim(strFileName) & vbCrLf
                Loop
                Close intFile
                
                ' Remove the extra line break at the end
                If Len(strTemp) > 0 Then
                    strTemp = Left(strTemp, Len(strTemp) - 2) ' Remove the extra vbCrLf
                End If
                
                ' Write the modified contents back to the file
                intFile = FreeFile
                Open objFile.Path For Output As intFile
                Print #intFile, strTemp
                Close intFile
            End If
        Next objFile
    Else
        MsgBox "Folder does not exist!"
    End If
    
    ' Clean up
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Leading and trailing spaces removed from all text files in the folder.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

I have multiple text files in particular location but files have empty space in last in first line. Please help in removing the all space from the all text file.

I have written the below VBA code but the same issue.

Comment: *"but the same issue."*: what is the issue after running this code? Did you step through the code with a debugger? Did it find the files? Did you get to the `Print` statement when you debugged?

Answer (score 0):

`Print` adds a trailing `CrLf` when its called, so that's where it comes from.

To suppress this add a semicolon to the call:

```
Print #intFile, strTemp;
```

Answer (score 0):

lightly modified you code. just check.

```
' Remove the extra line break at the end
                If Len(strTemp) > 0 Then
                If Right$(strTemp, 2) = vbCrLf Then
                    strTemp = Left(strTemp, Len(strTemp) - 2) ' Remove the extra vbCrLf
                    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, " ", "")
                    End If
                End If
```

Comment: No .. it is still not working. same space is still available as it is in all files.